# Why do I can't debug my project by VS code in win x86?

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-code, windows-7

when it's installing C# dependencies Visual Studio Code (powered by OmniSharp), I receive these message:
*[WARNING]: x86 Windows is not currently supported by the .NET Core debugger. Debugging will not be available.
[ERROR]: C# Extension failed to install the debugger package.*
I test new and older version of this extension, but it doesn't work.dotnet-sdk-3.1.419-win-x86
My system is win7 sp1 .x86.
I installed dotnet-sdk-6.0.300-win-x86 and dotnet-sdk-3.1.419-win-x86.
Thanks

Comment: It's not supported: https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/844

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Markus Meyer - perhaps make that an answer so the OP can accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not supported:
[https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/844][1]

> Unfortunately due the low usage of x86 Windows operating systems and many competing priorities, we are unable to fund adding x86 debugging support at this time. The C# extension will of course continue to function as an editor on x86 Windows.

> We recommend anyone looking for .NET debugging on x86 Windows to use Visual Studio instead. See https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/ for more information.
> [1]: https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/844